# Thinking of Java references in C++ way

Tags: java, c++, object, memory, reference

In Java, when we pass a java object argument to method `myMethod((MyObject) myObject)`, it is basically like passing a reference to object in C++ like `myFunction(& myObject)`. In such cases java developer has pretty much the same freedom like C++ programmer, if he wants to pass a reference he just passes an object, if he wants to get it copied, he does it manually in method.

But here is my question:

Let's say i have three different arrays with specific type of objects `MyObject`

`MyObject[] myObjectsOne`

`MyObject[] myObjectsTwo`

`MyObject[] myObjectsThree`

I need to have them separately, but i also need one alternative array which would be like a summary of those three mentioned above - for example used as single object to display the content of all three.

Scenario: 
To create the fourth array, which would represent the values of first three without copying the values actually anywhere. (Not allocating extra memory for these values)

In C++ i would just create a table with references to corresponding objects in those three tables.

I have always thought that in Java it is just being made for us, but when i started thinking about it, i am not really sure.

We have now also: `MyObject[] myObjectsFour`

And after performing..

```
myObjectsFour[0] = myObjectsOne[0];
```

**..does** accessing `myObjectsFour[0]` and `myObjectsOne[0]` mean actually accessing the same object on memory level? 
**Like i understand, it must be like that**, if it was not `myObjectsFour[0] = myObjectsOne[0].clone();`

Comment: You would be accessing the same object.

Comment: in Java you pass arguments to methods by **copies of references**, so if you reassign the reference to a different object in the function, the original reference (callers') is not affected.

Comment: Also references in c++ can refer to stack objects and you need to be careful then. Managed languages keep references to objects on heap and does garbage collection.

Comment: You answered the quostion yourself, but you could have used the == compare to test it, since == always compares the references of objects :)

Comment: The best C++ (and C) analogy of Java references I've come up with is that they are like pointers without pointer arithmetic. The C++ concept of references doesn't really exist in Java.

Comment: __Java has pointers__. (You may say otherwise, but what happens when you use `null`? The `NullPointerException` is thrown.)

Comment: Just another point of view. Java has pointers, but they aren't necessarily an address in memory, so you can't do pointer arithmetic. Every time you pass an object to a function, a new pointer to the same object is created and passed up the stack

Comment: Note: one difference is that 32-bit "reference" can be used for up to ~32 GB of heap.  This is because objects are 8-byte aligned on many JVMs.

Comment: You mean, "Just another pointer view", right?  Yuk, yuk, yuk...

Comment: @Kirby Took me a second... :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Objects are 8 byte aligned on many JVMs, but that doesn't mean 32 bit references can address more memory. A reference is commonly just a regular pointer. Compressing them would mean you'd need extra arithmetic to get the actual address when you use it, which is slow and rarely worth the space savings. Also, the bits that are zero due to alignment can be used for other purposes.

Comment: @delnan OpenJDK/HotSpot JVMs use compressed oops by default if the heap is over 2 GB.  The rule of thumb is that if you make the heap larger than 32 GB you need to jump to 48 GB to cover the extract overhead of using 643-bit references.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You're right, my bad. Learned something new :) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#compressedOop

Comment: @delnan I meant 64-bit not 643-bit ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is a slight misunderstanding from the background text:

> In Java, when we pass a java object argument to method
>   myMethod((MyObject) myObject), it is basically like passing a
>   reference to object in C++ like myFunction(& myObject).

Java is **not** a "pass-by-reference" language.  It always passes by value.  When you pass an object, you are passing a reference to that object *by value*.  This is analogous in C++ when you pass a pointer by value.

For example, in Java:

```
public void myMethod(MyObject myObject) {
    myObject = null;
}
```

The object passed as "MyObject" is only a reference by value.  So setting it to null does not affect the original object that was passed.  Correspondingly:

```
public void myMethod(MyObject myObject) {
    myObject.myIntProperty = 15;
}
```

Accessing members of the object, as above, does so to the actual object, since it is still a reference to that object.  If it helps, think of the passed in `myObject` as having a copy of the memory location that is the same as the memory location of the original object that was passed:

```
public void myMethod(MyObject myObject) {}
/* Example memory address: 0x009FC12A in memory, 
   a *copy* of the same address of the object that was passed */
```

---

With this mindset, let's take a look at your question.  What does this yield:

```
myObjectsFour[0] = myObjectsOne[0];
```

Well, as Java assigns the reference of the element *by value*, `myObjectsFour[0]` now points to precisely the same object.  This means:

```
myObjectsFour[0] = myObjectsOne[0];    
myObjectsFour[0].myIntProperty = 15;
```

Also changes the value of `myObjectsOne[0].myIntProperty` to be 15, just as above.  However doing this:

```
myObjectsFour[0] = myObjectsOne[0];
myObjectsFour[0] = null; // (or anything else, for that matter)
```

has no affect on `myObjectsOne[0]`.  It's not the *same* variable by the statement, `myObjectsFour[0] = myObjectsOne[0];`.  It's simply two variables that have a copy of the same reference.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Ofcourse it does, you wrote a decent answer. Thinking of passed object as of "a copy" of the reference to its memory address and not direct reference is vivid and makes very good sense why `=null` or `=new Obj()` on passed object won't affect the original one. Pass-by-value it is, but it would be way more clear if it was called pass-by-reference-value (for non-primitives).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would be accessing the same objects.

As some people in the comments pointed out, Java references are more like C++ pointer than C++ references, just with the difference that you don't have to delete them and that you can't do pointer arithmetic.

When an object is inserted in a Java array or a Java collection, the data structure points to the original object, not a copy.

- When you create a copy of an array or collection, the objects in it aren't copied. The new data structure points to the same objects.
- When you change something on an object in an array or collection, it also changes in all other collections the object was added to, because they all point to the same object.
- When you remove an object from an array or collection, it doesn't get deleted. Other pointers to it stay valid. (it gets deleted eventually by the garbage collector when no other pointers to it exist anymore).
- When a collection or array gets deleted, the objects it points to will not be affected (unless the garbage collector notices that no other pointers to them exist).